# Image not downloading from url

Tags: android, android-studio, bitmap

I try to download an image from URL to image view using bitmap in android studio. But there is an unknown error and I can't download the image.

Here is my code:

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ImageView imageView;
    Button button;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        imageView = findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        button = findViewById(R.id.button);
    }

    public void downloadImage(View view) {
        imageDownloader task = new imageDownloader();

        Bitmap myImage;
        ;
        try {
            myImage = task.execute("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/a/aa/Bart_Simpson_200px.png").get();

            imageView.setImageBitmap(myImage);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public class imageDownloader extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {

        @Override
        protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
            try {

                URL url = new URL(urls[0]);
                HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                urlConnection.connect();
                InputStream in = urlConnection.getInputStream();
                Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
                return myBitmap;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And when I try to download the image in the emulator nothing is shown and here is my logcat:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WLCfy.png)

Comment: You may lack the `INTERNET` permission in the manifest. Also, please use an image-loading library, such as Glide or Picasso. `AsyncTask` is deprecated, and `HttpURLConnection` should be deprecated.

Comment: `https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/a/aa/Bart_Simpson_200px.png").get();` Do not use the .get() on your task but set your bitmap in onPostExecute. And post the lines from your logcat as text

Comment: I got the solution using glide

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not use glide?

https://github.com/bumptech/glide

```
Glide.with(this)
        .asBitmap()
        .load(imagePath)
        .into(object : CustomTarget<Bitmap>(){
            override fun onResourceReady(resource: Bitmap, transition: Transition<in Bitmap>?) {
                imageView.setImageBitmap(resource)
            }
            override fun onLoadCleared(placeholder: Drawable?) {
                
            }
        })
```

Answer (score 0):

Better if you use glide or Picasso
But if want to use this model
Check this:
set image background on onPost method
Initialize image view onPre method
Before run task check network
And add policy to your Activity